# Laravel 10 queue worker generating hundreds of failed jobs due to "Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException"

Tags: php, laravel, queue, supervisord

I've got a Laravel 10 project running PHP 8.1, I'm using the latest version of Supervisor and have some 40 or so processes allocated to Supervisor as I process hundreds of jobs per minute via my database on various queues.

Time and time again in Laravel projects I find myself seeing this regular occurrence with the same kind of failed job popping up which doesn't account to any code errors.

> Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException

So much so that I've now got a cron running hourly to prune the failed jobs table for the past 12 hours, to put it into context, I have over 12,000 failed jobs for this error in this window.

Some would say to simply increase the number of `tries`, but this in turn would simply slow down my processing and my Jobs table would build up, and yes, I have my `retry_after` set slightly longer than my maximum timeout.

Here's one particular error, caused by my `certificates` queue:

```
Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: App\Jobs\CertificateChecker has been attempted too many times. in /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:785
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(519): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->maxAttemptsExceededException()
#1 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(429): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->markJobAsFailedIfAlreadyExceedsMaxAttempts()
#2 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(389): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process()
#3 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(176): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob()
#4 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(138): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon()
#5 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(121): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker()
#6 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#7 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#9 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#10 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(662): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call()
#11 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(211): Illuminate\Container\Container->call()
#12 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(326): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute()
#13 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(181): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#14 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1081): Illuminate\Console\Command->run()
#15 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(320): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#16 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(174): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#17 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(201): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#18 /var/www/domain-monitor-api/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#19 {main}
```

Here's my `queue.php` config file:

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Queue Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel's queue API supports an assortment of back-ends via a single
    | API, giving you convenient access to each back-end using the same
    | syntax for every one. Here you may define a default connection.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the connection information for each server that
    | is used by your application. A default configuration has been added
    | for each back-end shipped with Laravel. You are free to add more.
    |
    | Drivers: "sync", "database", "beanstalkd", "sqs", "redis", "null"
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        // for short running queues
        'database-short-running' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'short-running',
            'retry_after' => 80,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        // for long running queues
        'database-long-running' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'long-running',
            'retry_after' => 300,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 0,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'suffix' => env('SQS_SUFFIX'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Failed Queue Jobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These options configure the behavior of failed queue job logging so you
    | can control which database and table are used to store the jobs that
    | have failed. You may change them to any database / table you wish.
    |
    */

    'failed' => [
        'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database'),
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];
```

My `CertificateChecker` job file:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Certificate;
use App\Models\CertificateCheck;
use App\Models\Domain;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUniqueUntilProcessing;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class CertificateChecker implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUniqueUntilProcessing
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 1;

    /**
     * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 60;

    /**
     * The number of seconds after which the job's unique lock will be released.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $uniqueFor = 300;

    /**
     * The certificate id
     */
    protected $certificate;

    /**
     * When we checked this SSL
     */
    protected $checkedAt;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($certificate, $checkedAt)
    {
        $this->onConnection('database-short-running');
        $this->certificate = $certificate;
        $this->checkedAt = $checkedAt;
    }

    /**
     * The unique ID of the job.
     */
    public function uniqueId(): string
    {
        return 'certificate_check_id_'.$this->certificate;
    }

    /**
     * Get SSL data from domain
     */
    public function obtainCertificateData($domain)
    {
        try {
            $streamContext = stream_context_create([
                'ssl' => [
                    'capture_peer_cert' => true,
                ],
            ]);

            $domainToCheck = 'ssl://'.$domain.':443';
            $client = @stream_socket_client($domainToCheck,
                $errorNumber,
                $errorDescription,
                5,
                STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,
                $streamContext
            );

            // 110 - connection timed out (might be too short connection)
            // 111 - connection refused (could be wrong domain)
            // 113 - no route to host (wrong domain?)
            if (in_array($errorNumber, [110, 111, 113])) {
                return null;
            }

            // stream_socket_client returned false, likely an issue with checking
            // the ssl certificate and could be unsupported by our platform, or
            // incorrect input provided.
            if (! $client) {
                return null;
            }

            $response = stream_context_get_params($client);
            $response = openssl_x509_parse($response['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate'], false);

            return $response;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }

        // invalid ssl, or ssl doesn't exist
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get certificate
     */
    public function getCertificate($certificate)
    {
        $certificate = Certificate::where('id', $certificate)
                                  ->whereNull('disabled_at')
                                  ->first();

        return $certificate;
    }

    /**
     * Update certificate
     */
    public function updateCertificate($certificate, $fields)
    {
        $certificate->is_valid = $fields['is_valid'];
        $certificate->expires_on = $fields['expires_on'];
        $certificate->last_checked_at = $this->checkedAt;
        $certificate->save();
    }

    /**
     * Create a certificate check entry
     */
    public function createCertificateCheckEntry($certificate, $ssl)
    {
        $certificateCheck = new CertificateCheck;

        // meta
        $certificateCheck->certificate_id = $certificate->id;
        $certificateCheck->user_id = $certificate->user_id;

        // SSL subject
        if (isset($ssl['subject']) && ! empty($ssl['subject'])) {
            $certificateCheck->subject_country_name = (isset($ssl['subject']['countryName']) && ! empty($ssl['subject']['countryName'])) ? $ssl['subject']['countryName'] : null;

            $certificateCheck->subject_state_or_province_name = (isset($ssl['subject']['stateOrProvinceName']) && ! empty($ssl['subject']['stateOrProvinceName'])) ? $ssl['subject']['stateOrProvinceName'] : null;

            $certificateCheck->subject_locality_name = (isset($ssl['subject']['localityName']) && ! empty($ssl['subject']['localityName'])) ? $ssl['subject']['localityName'] : null;

            $certificateCheck->subject_organisation_name = (isset($ssl['subject']['organizationName']) && ! empty($ssl['subject']['organizationName'])) ? $ssl['subject']['organizationName'] : null;

            $certificateCheck->subject_common_name = (isset($ssl['subject']['commonName']) && ! empty($ssl['subject']['commonName'])) ? $ssl['subject']['commonName'] : null;
        }

        // SSL issuer
        if (isset($ssl['issuer']) && ! empty($ssl['issuer'])) {
            $certificateCheck->issuer_country_name = (isset($ssl['issuer']['countryName']) && ! empty($ssl['issuer']['countryName'])) ? $ssl['issuer']['countryName'] : null;

            $certificateCheck->issuer_state_or_province_name = (isset($ssl['issuer']['stateOrProvinceName']) && ! empty($ssl['issuer']['stateOrProvinceName'])) ? $ssl['issuer']['stateOrProvinceName'] : null;

            $certificateCheck->issuer_locality_name = (isset($ssl['issuer']['localityName']) && ! empty($ssl['issuer']['localityName'])) ? $ssl['issuer']['localityName'] : null;

            $certificateCheck->issuer_organisation_name = (isset($ssl['issuer']['organizationName']) && ! empty($ssl['issuer']['organizationName'])) ? $ssl['issuer']['organizationName'] : null;

            $certificateCheck->issuer_common_name = (isset($ssl['issuer']['commonName']) && ! empty($ssl['issuer']['commonName'])) ? $ssl['issuer']['commonName'] : null;
        }

        // SSL version number
        $certificateCheck->version = (isset($ssl['version']) && ! empty($ssl['version'])) ? intval($ssl['version']) : 1;

        // SSL serial numbers
        $certificateCheck->serial_number = (isset($ssl['serialNumber']) && ! empty($ssl['serialNumber'])) ? $ssl['serialNumber'] : null;
        $certificateCheck->serial_number_hex = (isset($ssl['serialNumberHex']) && ! empty($ssl['serialNumberHex'])) ? $ssl['serialNumberHex'] : null;

        // SSL signatures
        $certificateCheck->signature_type_sn = (isset($ssl['signatureTypeSN']) && ! empty($ssl['signatureTypeSN'])) ? $ssl['signatureTypeSN'] : null;
        $certificateCheck->signature_type_ln = (isset($ssl['signatureTypeLN']) && ! empty($ssl['signatureTypeLN'])) ? $ssl['signatureTypeLN'] : null;
        $certificateCheck->signature_type_nid = (isset($ssl['signatureTypeNID']) && ! empty($ssl['signatureTypeNID'])) ? $ssl['signatureTypeNID'] : null;

        // SSL valid from
        if (isset($ssl['validFrom_time_t']) && ! empty($ssl['validFrom_time_t'])) {
            try {
                $certificateCheck->valid_from = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($ssl['validFrom_time_t'])->toDateTimeString();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
            }
        }

        // SSL valid to
        if (isset($ssl['validTo_time_t']) && ! empty($ssl['validTo_time_t'])) {
            try {
                $certificateCheck->valid_to = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($ssl['validTo_time_t'])->toDateTimeString();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
            }
        }

        $certificateCheck->checked_at = $this->checkedAt;
        $certificateCheck->save();

        // return the saved check
        return $certificateCheck;
    }

    /**
     * Delete old records
     */
    public function deleteOldRecords($certificate)
    {
        $checks = CertificateCheck::select('id')
                                  ->where('certificate_id', $certificate->id)
                                  ->where('user_id', $certificate->user_id)
                                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                                  ->skip(3)
                                  ->take(10000)
                                  ->pluck('id')
                                  ->toArray();

        if (isset($checks) && count($checks) > 0) {
            CertificateCheck::whereIn('id', $checks)->chunk(500, function ($checks) {
                foreach ($checks as $check) {
                    $check->delete();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $certificate = $this->getCertificate($this->certificate);

        // the certificate
        if (! $certificate) {
            return;
        }

        // the domain name
        if (! isset($certificate->domain)) {
            return;
        }

        // get certificate data for domain
        $sslData = $this->obtainCertificateData($certificate->domain->domain);
        $savedCheck = $this->createCertificateCheckEntry($certificate, $sslData);

        // no ssl data
        if (! $sslData) {
            $this->updateCertificate($certificate, [
                'is_valid' => false,
                'expires_on' => null,
            ]);

            if ($savedCheck) {
                $this->deleteOldRecords($certificate);
            }
            return;
        }

        // no ssl expiry
        if (! isset($sslData['validTo_time_t']) || empty($sslData['validTo_time_t'])) {
            $this->updateCertificate($certificate, [
                'is_valid' => false,
                'expires_on' => null,
            ]);

            if ($savedCheck) {
                $this->deleteOldRecords($certificate);
            }
            return;
        }

        // valid
        if ($savedCheck && $savedCheck->valid_to) {
            $this->updateCertificate($certificate, [
                'is_valid' => true,
                'expires_on' => $savedCheck->valid_to,
            ]);

            if ($savedCheck) {
                $this->deleteOldRecords($certificate);
            }
            return;
        } else {
            $this->updateCertificate($certificate, [
                'is_valid' => false,
                'expires_on' => null,
            ]);

            if ($savedCheck) {
                $this->deleteOldRecords($certificate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running it on supervisor:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=on-demand-runs-now,cron,uptime,notifications,statistics-hourly,domains,dns,certificates,domains-expired,subscriptions,blacklists,listeners,statistics-daily,short-running,long-running,default --tries=2 --max-time=900
```

Is anyone able to defeat this error once and for all?